# executable binary cannot run on android marshmallow

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, cross-compiling, android-6.0-marshmallow

I built `ffmpeg` executable binary with shared libraries on Android. But when I run it on `Marshmallow`, I got the following error, the executable can't run.

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./bin/ffmpeg
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: cannot find "libavformat.so" from verneed[0] in DT_NEEDED list for "./bin/ffmpeg"
page record for 0xb6eee00c was not found (block_size=16)
```

I already added `--extra-ldexeflags="-pie"` when compiled the binary.

The executable binary run properly on pre `Marshmallow` device.

I didn't encounter such problem before, did I miss something important? How can I make this binary work on `Marshmallow`?

**More information about my environment.**

I used `android-ndk-r10e` with

`SYSROOT=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-19/arch-arm` and toolchains version is

`arm-linux-androideabi-gcc (GCC) 4.9 20140827 (prerelease)`

If I built `ffmpeg` into a single executable binary (build the static libraries and then build into binary), it run properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found a similar issue from [here](https://github.com/eryngii-mori/android-developer-preview/issues/2239). There is a problem with my share libraries.

`FFmpeg` build script disable `SONAME` for android build, so there is no `SONAME` found when reading library by command

`arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -d libavutil.so |grep soname`

Change the configuration script like following, it will work.

```
    android)
    disable symver
    enable section_data_rel_ro
    SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME)'
    SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS=
    # soname not set on purpose
    # soname should set for new version Android
    SHFLAGS='-shared -Wl,-soname,$$(word 1,$$(subst ., ,$$(@F))).so'
    # SHFLAGS=-shared
```

After then, recompile `ffmpeg` to generate share libraries, and I got the result I want,

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -d libavutil.so |grep soname
0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libavutil.so]
```

Then, the executable binary run properly.

Comment: the link can't be reached now. :(